# How can I test a button with a scroll down function on cucumber?

Tags: jquery, web, cucumber, slidedown

I'm writing cucumber tests for a website, and I've gotten completely stuck on this one. On the website's checkout procedure, there is a button that triggers a slidedown into the next part of the checkout procedure (on the same page). The button is defined in jQuery as follows:

```
    $("#next1").click(function(event){
    $('#step1').slideUp(500);
    $('#step1top').css('color','#036070');
    $('#step1top').removeClass('active');
    $('#step2top').css('color','#fff');
    $('#step2').slideDown(500);
    $('#step2top').addClass('active');
 });
```

There are several others like this, and when you inspect element on the site, the HTML shown is as follows:

`< img id="next1" src="/images/next.png" style="float:right;" >`

I've tried to write steps that click inside elements.  For example:

```
When /^I click "([^"]*)" inside element "([^"]*)"$/ do |button, element_name| 
  begin
    evaluate_script("$('#{element_name}').trigger('mouseover')")
  rescue Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError
  end
end
```

However, nothing that I've tried seems to work. Does anyone have any advice?